# Embed content from another TikiWiki page into current page

Tags: tiki-wiki

I have a TikiWiki page describing an algorithm, for example

```
To calculate the square root of a number $x$ in R, use sqrt($x$).
```

In another TikiWiki page I include the algorithm in a bigger process, e.g.

```
Step 4: Now calculate the square root of this number, see ((square_root_in_R|here)).
```

However, I would like to embed the line `To calculate the square root of a number $x$ in R, use sqrt($x$).` from my other page into Step 4, so that the user does not have to refer to the other page to get the algorithm.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to use the wikiplugin INCLUDE:

```
{INCLUDE(page=square_root_in_R)}{INCLUDE}
```